# Intercept Exceptions for logging with CDI's AOP on Java EE 7

Tags: exception, logging, cdi, aop, java-ee-7

I have the following class snippet, from which I'd like to remove the repetitive logging code and move it to an Interceptor using CDI's AOP.

```
/**
 * Javadoc omitted
 */
public abstract class JpaDao<T extends LongIdentifiable> implements
        GenericDao<T> { 

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Long persist(T type) throws GeneralPersistenceException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Can't persist null");
        }

        try {
            entityManager.persist(type);
            return type.getId();
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            String message = "Failed to persist an entity";
            logger.error(message, e);
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public T merge(T type) throws GeneralPersistenceException {
        if (type == null) {
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Can't merge null");
        }

        try {
            T mergedType = entityManager.merge(type);
            return mergedType;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            String message = "Failed to merge an entity";
            logger.error(message, e);
            throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the code snippet below, which repeats in `persist` e `merge` methods

```
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    String message = "Failed to persist an entity";
    logger.error(message, e);
    throw new GeneralPersistenceException(message, e);
}
```

The candidate code to replace the snippet above is the following:

```
} catch (PersistenceException e) {
    throw new GeneralPersistenceException("Failed to persist an entity", e);
}
```

In another words, I'd like that each time a `GeneralPersistenceException` is thrown, a log message is written. My Exception is the following:

```
public class GeneralPersistenceException extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6057737927996676949L;

    public GeneralPersistenceException() {
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public GeneralPersistenceException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

As you could see, the Exception has only constructors.
Given this scenario, I have the following questions:

1. The best strategy to solve this problem in a Java EE 7 compliant application, is using AOP with CDI?
2. In case it's AOP, should I intercept the `GeneralPersistenceException`?
3. Is it possible to intercept `GeneralPersistenceException`'s constructors, or only methods (which don't exists yet)?
4. Is there something already implemented for this purpose and I'm reinventing the wheel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps DeltaSpike's Exception Control is what you're looking for? http://deltaspike.apache.org/documentation/core.html#ExceptionControl

Comment: It's a good alternative but it is not what I'm looking for. I really want to provide such exception handling using CDI's AOP or anything already provided by the Java EE spec.

Comment: Your question was `Is there something already implemented for this purpose and I'm reinventing the wheel?` I simply pointed to the existing wheel for you.

Comment: It wasn't the only question, please note the `The best strategy to solve this problem in a Java EE 7 compliant application, is using AOP with CDI?`. But I'm not arguing with you. Thanks anyway for your advice but this is not   exactly what I'm looking for, as said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't intercept exception since it's created using **new*, and it will not be managed by CDI. And in practice you should not intercept in that way.
The solution you are looking for is to intercept calls in you service, catch your exception there and log it.

Comment: `And in practice you should not intercept in that way`. @win_wave, could you explain why?

Comment: Intercepted objects must be managed by CDI, you cannot avoid that. CDI creates objects in certain scopes, but Exception instance should live only time from it throwing until it's catch. There is no need or use case to manage it by CDI. I think that exception should be as light as possible.

Comment: Fair enough. I will work on the proposed solution. Thank you @win_wave.